# iOS PlayGameServices expecting valid application id, but there is

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, prime31

I configured the Prime31 plugin for Unity and play games, and on Android all works smooth.

But when I try to do something on iOS I have the following error:

```
[GPGManager modelForApplicationId:] Expecting valid application id.
```

The error is showed when I use the init function. I have GPGApplicationID set on the info.plist of the application. I pass the clientId in init. So, where is the problem?

It's only an hypothesis, but I think that if the application works very well with Android maybe the real problem is in the PlayGameServices configuration, so if you don't know exactly how the Prime31 plugin works but have some ideas on possible faults in configuration, please, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to authenticate still, or does that keep you from successfully authenticating a user?  I am having the same issue with the plugin currently.

One workaround that seems to work is performing the init() and authenticate() immediately during Startup().  For whatever reason, when performed this way my user will successfully authenticate.  If I then log out, and try to authenticate again, I get the  "Mismatched authentication" error which seems to be related to the "Expecting valid application id." warning we are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't understand what do you mean with "Startup()", I put the init in an Awake in an object loaded at the start of the game, but nothing changed.

I'm not sure I can't authenticate a user, my code stops if the init fails, but it is really possible without initialize correctly the plugin?